# DAX formula in Sql Server Analysis Services

Tags: formula, dax, ssas-2012

I am new to DAX, How can I calculate the runs of a particular player from below table. My table name **PlayersData**. For example, want to the total runs of the sachin tendulkar from the table. Need Dax formula..

I tried this for getting the occurrences of virat Kohli in the table:

```
:=COUNTROWS(VALUE(PlayersData[Name] = "Virat Kohli"))
```

But , it shows the Error..

Thanks in advance...

[image: Excel Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the Query given my required result:

**TotalRunsOfKohli:=CALCULATE(SUM('Players Data'[Runs]),'Players Data'[Name]="Virat Kohli")**